# Where is set the variable $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()?

Tags: magento-1.7, template, wishlist

I can see in phtml files some tests like:

```
 <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
```

I want but to know where is set this variable (isAllow or not)?

I am using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It gets set on

system > configuration > wishlist > general(General Options) > active(Enable)

```
app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php line 192

    public function isAllow()
   {
         if (Mage::getStoreConfig('wishlist/general/active')) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Without the first paragraph this would be a good answer. Why override if you can just use the configuration?